# to find the probabilty distribution of a new variable

Tags: distributions, t-distribution

If a random variable X follows t-distribution with n degrees of freedom, then what is the probability distribution of X^2?

Comment: It has F-Snedecor distribution $F(1, n)$

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad maybe you would like to convert your comment to answer by expanding it a little bit? Btw, welcome to our site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that for $T \sim t(n)$ by definition

$$T = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{U/n}}$$

Where $Z \sim N(0,1), U \sim \chi^2(n)$. Thus

$$T^2 = \frac{Z^2}{U/n} = \frac{Z^2/1}{U/n} \sim F(1,n)$$

Since $Z^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$ and $F(p,q)$ is defined as

$$F(p,q) \sim F =  \frac{U/p}{V/q},\  \text{for}\ \  U \sim \chi^2(p),\ \ V \sim \chi^2(q)$$